# PHP - First PHP site

Tags: php

This is my first PHP website that is actually going to be published. One of the items that I want to do is to create a slideshow inside my PHP page.

I am not quite sure how to do this.  I am hoping someone can give my some good source info.

Also I understand this is a vague question but I am not sure where to start.

Comment: Slideshows are usually made with JS. This means you want your PHP to create the HTML, and then use JS for the actual slideshow (I personally prefer [Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/)). - Google "[php javascript slideshow tutorial](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+javascript+slideshow+tutorial)," and look at pages [like this one](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/externalphp2.shtml)

Comment: If I was you, I would start by reading this book cover to cover. http://www.amazon.com/PHP-MySQL-Web-Development-4th/dp/0672329166

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time since I was in your shoes, but the current web is much, much easier to work than when I was first learning (2001-2004). For instance, you should really consider jQuery and by extension some of the better jQuery libraries. I think you would like Colorbox:

http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

Comment: So I should be able to step in and out of .php w/o issue correct and it should render fine?  I am trying to recycle some of my old slideshow code but it is not working.

Comment: I'm not sure you're following the server/client model quite right. For slideshows, the browser needs to know what the bounds of the slideshow are, plus various things like greatest and least visible variable values are; if you're trying to show a series of images, you need to make your server output to the client (browser) the boundary you want it to display, and have the JS be able to handle that boundary.

Comment: If you have old code you're trying to rehabilitate, you need to start a question about that code, where you reference it, and have a clear purpose/question you're asking. You could do this with this question, for instance.